# Cockroachdb varchar column length isn't flexible

Tags: sql, spring-boot, flyway, varchar, cockroachdb

I have a spring boot application that connects to Cockroachdb. I have the following script in my flyway using which the table gets created:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sample_table (
                                    name varchar,
                                    groups varchar,
                                    PRIMARY KEY (name));
```

The application starts fine, but whenever there is a value for the 'groups' column that is greater than 255 length, I get an error :

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type VARCHAR(255)
```

In the sql script, I have mentioned the column 'groups' as 'varchar' which should not restrict the length so I am not sure why am I getting this error.

Comment: Don't know Cockroachdb, but varchar usually should be defined with (maximum) length, eg: `varchar(1000)`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an implicit default limit on varchar in CockroachDB. This error indicates that the `groups` column was initialized with the type `varchar(255)` when the table was created. Running `SHOW CREATE TABLE sample_table;` should confirm this.

It's possible that something unexpected is  going on in the flyway and the table is not being created how you want it to be created.